# Not possible to use conjunction 'when' in this case?

Tags: word-choice

This is a question from a text book.
"Mr. Thompson wrote to the main office to find out (   ) his budget would be for the following year."
There are 4 options given.
(A) what
(B) who
(C) when
(D) it 
The answer (A) is given in this case.  I can agree with that, but I also feel that "(C) when" can be used in this case.  If it is not allowed to "when" grammatically, could you please advise me the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use “when” because “his budget” is not an event that happens at a point in time. “When” is only used in situations where time is involved. If you provide your reasoning on why you think “when” works, I can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.   Your explanation is very convincing.  Now I can understand "when" cannot be used in this sentence.  For my confirmation, it is acceptable to use "when" in the following sentence? [Mr. Thompson wrote to the main office to find out when the next monthly meeting would be held next month.]

Comment: Yes, that works

Answer (score 1):

You can use *"when"* to introduce a single completed event that takes place in the middle of a longer activity or event. In these cases, you usually use a continuous verb in the main clause to describe the background event:

> He was walking back to his flat when he heard an explosion.

Depending on the context, when can mean ‘after’ or ‘at the same time’.

Compare:

> When you open the file, check the second page. *- **when** meaning ‘after’*
>
> I eat ice cream when I am on holiday. *- **when** meaning ‘at the same time’*

We often use *"just"* with *"when"* or *"as"* to express things happening at exactly the same time:

> The phone always rings just when I’m closing the front door.
>
> She was a brilliant gymnast, but she had a terrible accident in 1999, just as her career was taking off.